# user id is not the same when creating a file

Tags: user-management, username

I just noticed that whatever file I create does not have me as userID/owner, instead it has another user (a generic access account). I'm not sure where to start debuging this issue since I'm new to this level and taking the system over from the previous IT. Could someone please explain what does it mean? it is worth mentioning that I'm indeed logged in as myself and I have sudo rights.

Thanks in advance

ubuntu version 16.04 LTS

Comment: Please tell us how you create the file, and what owner ID it gets. (For example, do you use `sudo some-command` to create the file? Then you should expect to get the owner `root`.)

Comment: so far creating a folder `mkdir` or a text file `vi`, and no I'm not using sudo in these cases.

Comment: What is your userID and what user-ID is the owner of the created directory or file?

Comment: my userID is `hasani` and group is bioinformatics, there is a generic user called `bioinformatics` which is used to mount partitions or share data. Now, whatever I create is always under this user name. the working partition is created with this user

Comment: Are you creating the directory or file in a Microsoft file system, FAT32, exFAT or NTFS? In that case all permissions and ownerships will be set (and cannot be changed) when mounting the partition. (In a linux file system, for example `ext4,` you can set permissions and ownership individually for each directory and file. So when you create a file you are also the owner like you expect it to work.)

Comment: I suspected that with one drive, it is indeed a ms file system. However the other drive shouldn't be.

Comment: Please tell us what file system there is in the other drive. Anyway, if you *create a file in your home directory*, you should become owner of that file (you can check that).

Comment: ext4, and yes when I'm in my home I'm the owner. I'm trying to understand why and whether this is a ticking bomb? is it because from linux side both drives were mounted by this user so automatically everything will belong to it?

Comment: Maybe the partition with `ext4` is mounted with some special options. Please ask the person who made the system mount the partition like that. Maybe it is only some directories in that partition that behave like this.